# How to fix this Error "The following arguments are required: command"

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I am beginner on AWS. I am working on Windows environment. Anybody knows "How to fix the error below"?. I tried to use "aws s3 la" and "aws ec2 describe-intances", but this doesn't fix the error.

[image]

Comment: What is the actual command you are trying to use?

Comment: I am trying to use aws command

Comment: when i used "aws" command, I got this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "aws s3 la" and "aws ec2 describe-intances"

The commands don't work because they have **spelling mistakes**. They should be:

```
aws s3 ls
```

and

```
aws ec2 describe-instances
```

Comment: when I used your codes I got this error ubuntu@ip-172-31-15-36:~$ aws ec2 describe-instances

Unknown output type: None
ubuntu@ip-172-31-15-36:~$

Comment: @Elwakdy Try `aws ec2 describe-instances --output text --region <your-region>`

Comment: I tried this and got this error ubuntu@ip-172-31-15-36:~$ aws ec2 describe-instances --output text --region <us-east-2>
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Comment: I got the same error  error: the following arguments are required: command

Comment: @Elwakdy The command is correct. Maybe you typed it out with mistakes again.

Comment: When I write your command is run well, but when I write the command "aws", I got the same error

Comment: ubuntu@ip-172-31-15-36:~$ aws
Note: AWS CLI version 2, the latest major version of the AWS CLI, is now stable and recommended for general use. For more information, see the AWS CLI version 2 installation instructions at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2.html

usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: the following arguments are required: command

Comment: @The command is `aws ec2 describe-instances --output text --region us-east-2`. Just using `aws` is incorrect.

Comment: so how can I see all information about whole instances?

Comment: @Elwakdy I would suggest making new question. Your new issues are quite far from the original question posted.

Comment: like "instance ID", group securities and all other information about all instances

Comment: I just need to make sure that the error has been fixed and I can see all the information about the instances. there is a way can help me to see all information for all instances.  I would be much appreciated

Comment: @Elwakdy Does the following `aws ec2 describe-instances --output json --region us-east-2` work? You can make new question with relevant error messages and expect output. This way others could also help.

Comment: It works but I didn't getting the information about all instances in Jason format so it hard to know if the command works and give me about all instances or not

Comment: @Elwakdy The output from the command given is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html#examples). I don't know what are "all" information that you require.

Comment: All information about the all instances include the "security groups", "Name", "Instance ID" and etc.

Comment: @Elwakdy So `describe-instances` gives these information.

Comment: Yes, it gives. I closed all windows and rerun it again with writing the same commands and everything now is ok. Thank you so much

Comment: @Elwakdy Glad to hear it worked out:-)

Comment: when I tried to see all the information about my instance using this command  aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-052c194ae1c26b323 it doesn't work ... could you please advise me why it doesn't work. I got this command from the link you sent me

Comment: @Elwakdy Don't know. Maybe the instance is in a different region? Maybe the id is wrong? I think you should make new question with relevant error messages if you have further issues.